# Using jquery mobile and Rails RESTful controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-mobile

I recently tried to integrate jquery mobile views in a Rails 3 project [Rails jquery mobile Routing/Rendering Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055339/rails-jquery-mobile-routing-rendering-issue). I quickly found out that jquery mobile doesn't work in some instances with RESTful controller actions:

PUT/posts  This works when I create a new record with the Create Action, however, when it redirects to the Show Action, clicking the back button doesn't do anything and you must refresh the browser in order for the index page to appear.

PUT/posts/:id  Same as above except through the Update Action.

I've been searching for a resource to explain the mechanics for how to make this work but have been unsuccessful.  I think it has to do with jquery-ajax.  I'm currently listening to an excellent screencast from peepcode on jquery-ajax, but I'm not able to tie it into rails yet. Can anyone point me to a resource that provides an overview for integrating jquery mobile with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Rails so I cannot vouch for its accuracy however I answered a question yesterday where someone had successfully used this tutorial: http://fuelyourcoding.com/getting-started-with-jquery-mobile-rails-3/

Another question I answered a few days back had a link to this podcast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Hope these can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  The tutorial mostly works except it suffers from the same issue I had with the other tutorial.  Namely, getting the list of records (index) to update after create and/or update.  The railscasts is very informative, however, it uses jqtouch and I'm trying to implement jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Although not ideal, since it won't use ajax, I found the easiest fix is to put data-ajax=false on the back link.

```
<%= link_to 'Back', your_path, 'data-icon' => 'back', 'data-ajax' => false %>
```