# Rails redirect_to shows incorrect URL in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, jquery-mobile

I have 2 controllers: Games and Players.

1. Games creates my game and the first player, and redirects to players 'edit' action.
2. User submits updates to the player, and the Players controller redirects back to games 'show' action.

The user flow works well (the player is updated and the user is shown the game show page), except the URL in the browser upon the final submit still shows 'www.server.com/players/:id'.  If I hit refresh on the browser, it will go to the player's show action (as the URL suggests), instead of refreshing the games/show content that is currently on the screen.

What is the preferred approach for fixing this behavior?

Games Controller:

```
def create
  @game = Game.new(params[:game])
  if @game.save
    redirect_to edit_player_path (@game.players.first)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Players Controller:

```
def update
  @game = current_game
  @player = @game.players.find(params[:id])
  if @player.update_attributes(params[:player])
    redirect_to @game
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

ANSWERS to follow up Questions:

current_game is a helper method to retrieve a game (same design as Rails Tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out )

```
def current_game
  @current_game ||= Game.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

routes.rb:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
get "static_pages/home"

resources :games
resources :players
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

UPDATE:

I think I have narrowed down the problem.  It has to do with jquery_mobile_rails.

I was able to reproduce the behavior by creating a new project with 2 scaffolds and set up routing in the controllers as above.  The URL is updated properly without JQM.  When I added jquery_mobile_rails gem, and performed a POST, the URL no longer updates.

There is further discussion on the web about this (see links below), but so far I was not able to find a solution:

[Rails jquery mobile Routing/Rendering Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055339/rails-jquery-mobile-routing-rendering-issue?rq=1)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/restful-resources-rails-3-and-jquery-mobile

Comment: can you show your routes.rb code.

Comment: In players controller, what current_game?